# Group By Clause - Need Assistance

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

This is my first post. I am new to SQL. I have the below code that I added `MAX` to so that I would not get the error:

> must be aggregated or in the GROUP BY clause

Ultimately, I would like to `GROUP BY` *playerID* only with the AB, HRs, summed up by player (playerID). How can I fix this? How to avoid using the `MAX` (or any aggregate) function? What more info can I provide?

Here is the code:

```
SELECT
    MAX(teamID) AS teamID,
    MAX(People.playerID) AS playerID,
    MAX(People.nameFirst) AS nameFirst,
    MAX(People.nameLast) AS nameLast,
    MAX(CONCAT(People.nameFirst, ' ', People.nameLast)) AS 'Full Name',
    MAX(CONCAT(People.birthCity, ', ', People.birthState, ', ', People.birthCountry)) AS 'Place of Birth',
    SUM(Batting.AB) AS AB,
    SUM(Batting.H) AS H,
    SUM(Batting."2B") AS "2B",
    SUM(Batting."3B") AS "3B",
    SUM(Batting.HR) AS HR,
    SUM(Batting.BB) AS BB,
    SUM(Batting.HBP) AS HBP

FROM 
    People

JOIN Batting ON
     Batting.playerID = People.playerID

WHERE 
    teamID = 'NYA' AND
    nameFirst IS NOT NULL

GROUP BY
    People.playerID

ORDER BY
    'Full Name' ASC
```

**Thank you in advance**.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It is quite hard to infer what you want from your query and explanation. To make your question easier to understand, you would need to share a few records of sample data for both table `People` and `Batting`, along with the corresponding expected output.

Comment: Also would you please tag your question with the RDBMS that you are using: mysql, oracle, sql-server...?

Comment: What is the issue with current query?

Comment: Nothing is wrong per se with the query, my question is really do I need to add the MAX in front of the column names that dont have aggregation?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select all these columns without aggregating on them you must include them in the GROUP BY clause:

```
SELECT
teamID,
People.playerID,
People.nameFirst,
People.nameLast,
CONCAT(People.nameFirst, ' ', People.nameLast)) AS 'Full Name',
CONCAT(People.birthCity, ', ', People.birthState, ', ', People.birthCountry)) AS 'Place of Birth',
SUM(Batting.AB) AS AB,
SUM(Batting.H) AS H,
SUM(Batting."2B") AS "2B",
SUM(Batting."3B") AS "3B",
SUM(Batting.HR) AS HR,
SUM(Batting.BB) AS BB,
SUM(Batting.HBP) AS HBP
FROM People JOIN Batting 
ON Batting.playerID = People.playerID
WHERE teamID = 'NYA' AND nameFirst IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY People.playerID,People.nameFirst,People.nameLast,People.birthCity,People.birthState,People.birthCountry
ORDER BY 'Full Name' ASC
```

This does not pose any problem in the grouping of the rows, since all these columns identify each row of the table `People`